# click on element hidden due to md-backdrop class

Tags: cypress

Unable to click on the "**stage1**".

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element:
>
> ```html
> <img class="add-achievement" src="images/gamification/add-entry-icon.e4f22ffd.png"
>    alt="add stage achievement" ng-click="addStage(achievement.stage)" role="button"
>    tabindex="0">
> ```
>
> is being covered by another element:
>
> ```html
> <md-backdrop class="md-select-backdrop md-click-catcher ng-scope" style="position: fixed;">
>   </md-backdrop>
> ```
>
> Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
>
> https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with

**Code:**

```js
cy.get('#stage').click({force: true})
cy.get('#select_container_218 > md-select-menu > md-content')
  .invoke('show')
  .should('not.be.visible')
cy.contains('stage1')
  .invoke('show')
  .click({force: true})
```

Comment: I am trying to click on 'stage1' but getting the error.I tried using {force:True} but it is not working.

Comment: I have a similiar problem with "_CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:_" though the element is definitely visible. The page linked at the bottom of the message mentions: "_There have been situations where Cypress does not correctly allow you to interact with an element that should be interactable. If that’s the case, [Open an issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new)._"

Comment: I opened an according issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4897